# RESTful query of nested models in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models `Users` and `Tags`. A user `has_and_belongs_to_many tags`, and a tag `has_and_belongs_to_many users`.

Say I would like to search for all enabled users, who are tagged with environment.

Currently I hit the show action of the tag controller like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/tags/environment?search=enabled
```

and I'm building a search like this:

tag_controller.rb

```
 def show
    @users = Tag.search(params)
    @tag = params[:id]
    respond_with @users
  end
```

tag.rb model

```
def self.search(term)
  if term
   where(slug:term[:id]).first.users
  end
end
```

I'm realizing very quickly this makes no sense at all. Say I would like to search on an associated property of Users, which is passed in the params[:search] say I would like to filter them down by @user.enabled? or @user.zipcode.

**How do I build a complicated query across two models using rails in a RESTful way?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
User.where(enabled: true).joins(:tags).where(term: 'environment')
```

just beware not to have `enabled` on `Tag` and `term` on `User` or you will have to prefix those with table names.

EDIT:
with prefix

```
User.where('users.enabled = ?', true).joins(:tags).where('tags.term = ?', 'environment')
```